# Make starts in wrong directory under FreeBSD

Tags: makefile, freebsd

I have a very simple Makefile that just shells out to another Makefile:

```
all:
    cd src && make all
```

My directory structure (the `Makefile` is in the top-level directory):

```
[I] mqudsi@php ~/bbcp> tree -d
.
├── bin
│   └── FreeBSD
├── obj
│   └── FreeBSD
├── src
└── utils
```

This works just fine under Linux, but under FreeBSD, it gives an error about `src` not being found.

To debug, I updated the Makefile command to `pwd; cd src && make all` and I discovered that *somehow* when I run `make` in the top-level directory, it is being executed under `./obj` instead, meaning it's looking for `./obj/src/` to `cd` into.

Aside from the fact that I have no clue why it's doing that, I presumed for sure that calling `gmake` instead of `make` under FreeBSD would take care of it, but that wasn't the case (and I'm relieved, because I can't believe there is that huge of a difference between BSD make and GNU make in terms of core operation).

The odd thing is, deleting `obj` makes everything work perfectly. So in the presence of an `obj` directory, `make` cds into `./obj` first; otherwise it executes as you'd expect it to.

Comment: would `make -C src all` behave as expected?

Comment: @FelixPalmen no, that behaves identically. You can check out my code here, I'm maintaining an abandoned tool called bbcp: https://github.com/mqudsi/bbcp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

From the FreeBSD `make` man page:

```
.OBJDIR      A path to the directory where the targets are built.  Its
             value is determined by trying to chdir(2) to the follow-
             ing directories in order and using the first match:

             1.   ${MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX}${.CURDIR}

              (Only if `MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX' is set in the environ-
              ment or on the command line.)

             2.   ${MAKEOBJDIR}

              (Only if `MAKEOBJDIR' is set in the environment or
              on the command line.)

             3.   ${.CURDIR}/obj.${MACHINE}

             4.   ${.CURDIR}/obj

             5.   /usr/obj/${.CURDIR}

             6.   ${.CURDIR}

             Variable expansion is performed on the value before it's
             used, so expressions such as
               ${.CURDIR:S,^/usr/src,/var/obj,}
             may be used.  This is especially useful with
             `MAKEOBJDIR'.

             `.OBJDIR' may be modified in the makefile via the special
             target `.OBJDIR'.  In all cases, make will chdir(2) to
             the specified directory if it exists, and set `.OBJDIR'
             and `PWD' to that directory before executing any targets.
```

The key part being

> **In all cases, make will chdir(2) to specified directory if  it exists, and set `.OBJDIR'`PWD' to that directory before executing any targets.**

By contrast, the [GNU make manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) makes no such reference to any sort of automatic determination of `OBJDIR`, only that it will be used if it is set.

The solution was to override the `OBJDIR` variable via the pseudotarget `.OBJDIR`:

```
.OBJDIR: ./

all:
    cd src && make
clean:
    cd src && make clean
```

An alternative solution is to prefix the `cd` targets with `${CURDIR}`, which isn't modified after the `chdir` into `OBJDIR`.

I don't get why `gmake` behaved the same way, however. That feels almost like a bug to me.