# FreeBSD make creates obj directory

Tags: makefile, freebsd

Under FreeBSD, for some odd reason every time I execute a simple `Makefile`, it tries to create an `obj` directory under the current PWD.

I thought it might have to do with [the default `.OBJDIR` for FreeBSD make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675365/make-starts-in-wrong-directory-under-freebsd), but setting `.OBJDIR: ./` does not change this behavior.

This causes me problems down the line because it conflicts with SConstruct, but I managed to work around that by removing all read/write permissions for `./obj`, however I still want to know why every time I run `make`, it tries to create the `./obj` directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Whithout the Makefile it will be difficult to understand your problem. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45675365/2371524) explains that FreeBSD make only tries to `chdir()` to an `.OBJDIR`, but doesn't create it. There must be some other reason in your Makefile, so I second @RenaudPacalet's comment.

Comment: Object directories *do* get automatically created but only if inside of /usr/src. If it is being created outside of there it is a bug and I'd love to hear about it since I implemented this change.

Comment: @BryanDrewery this was obviously many, many moons ago on an older version of FreeBSD. I still have the VM image saved somewhere and could probably dig it out to debug further if I were sufficiently motivated, but we no longer run into this problem in 2022 on FreeBSD 13 (and have also bid scons adieu). I’ve written my share of voodoo-filled Makefiles abusing documented behavior but never did figure this one out. Thanks for letting me know there’s a chance I’m not entirely crazy!

Answer (score 0):

`make` does not create any `${.OBJDIR}` automatically -- something in your `Makefile`s must be explicitly creating that (or trying to).

Could you post the makefile and/or the output of a `make`-run?

You can affect the value of the variable by setting `MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX` or `MAKEOBJDIR` in the environment or on command-line (neither can be set in `/etc/make.conf`).

See `make(1)` for more details.